# Question conerning the determimant of the sum of two matrices- revised format

Tags: matrices, determinant

Sorry for the precedent "version" of my question.

Here (in an attached file) there is a complete version of this question I have concerning the determinant of the sum of two matrices.

I'm sorry again for my incompetence in editing mathematical equations. I hope however that the question is formulated in a clear enough format.

Thank you in advance

[Question-Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jigIk.jpg)
[Question-Page2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B8Db.jpg)